# Does Flashpoint ever indicate directly that it takes place in Toronto?

Tags: flashpoint

With a little investigation, you can figure out that the show *Flashpoint* takes place in Toronto. There are plenty of cityscape shots and the buildings match. But they seem to work really hard to make it seem like a generic metropolitan city.

**Do they *ever* give it away through dialogue or visible words?**

Is there any dialogue where they say they're in Toronto? Are there any badges or logos that say they're in Toronto?

Comment: Being filmed in Toronto is not evidence that a movie or show is set in Toronto.  It is very common to film movies and television shows in places hundreds or thousands of miles away from their fictional settings.  And nobody goes to alien planets to film scenes set on them!  The filming location is not a good clue to the fictional setting.

Comment: Lots of TV and movie productions are done in Canada because of lower costs and government incentives to encourage it, and it's nearby. Also similar culture - comparable economies so no immigration hassles, credit cards work, you can drink the water, you don't need interpreters, and you can find American looking locations just about anywhere.

Comment: TVTropes calls this [Canada Does Not Exist](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CanadaDoesNotExist).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashpoint_(TV_series)) that the show's setting was originally "not identified". Bill Mustos, head of one of the show's production companies, [explained](https://mediadecoder.blogs.nytimes.com//2008/07/11/canadians-sneak-across-border-hide-on-cbs/):

> You’re not going to see a show that is screaming "Canada". It’s a show in a big sophisticated urban city where crises take place. The stories we’re trying to tell are universal stories.

However, the Wikipedia article also lists various subtle visual clues as to the show's location, such as "ex-Toronto police cars with the Toronto police logo still on them", and "a paramedic whose shirt reads 'Toronto EMS Paramedic'" in the Series 1 finale 'Between Heartbeats'. There are so many that I won't bother listing all of them, but in terms of "dialogue or visible words":

> In the first part of the series finale [...] the city's name is shown and mentioned twice, first in a caption that reads "Toronto City Hall" and then when a dispatcher calls for crews to be sent to Toronto immediately.

So in short, yes, the show explicitly identifies itself as taking place in Toronto.

Comment: The last part is the answer I'm looking for. Very impressive that they go 4 full seasons and most of the 5th season without exposing the "secret".

Comment: Wait a sec - I missed part of your answer. There's an episode where a paramedic's shirt literally says "Toronto EMS Paramedic"? Do you happen to know which episode? If it's before the series finale, that would be the best answer to my question.

Comment: It's in "Between Heartbeats", the Series 1 finale. I'll edit that in.

Comment: "Between Heartbeats" is a Season 2 episode (not Season 1). Can you give any details? Like a particular scene or a minutes/seconds for when it appears

Comment: I've scanned through that episode, there's really only 1 scene with paramedics (after Jules gets shot) and I don't see "Toronto" on anyone's uniform. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know. Like I said, I'm just going off the Wikipedia article, I've only watched about two episodes of *Flashpoint* and barely remember anything about them.

Comment: Fair enough. Your answer is still correct, I checked and the series finale has Toronto in the dialogue. But I would be super interested if it happened before then.